# Getting previous version of dclsockets70.bpl to work for delphi

Tags: delphi

I am very new to Delphi and using Delphi XE5 trial version.  My question is how on earth do I get dclsockets70.bpl to work for old projects?

I have looked at a lot of post to get an idea but all I am getting is

```
"select Component | Install Packages | Add ..."
```

I do this and when looking in my 7.0 Delphi folder and there is nothing called dclsockets70.bpl.  Is this due because I am only on the trial version?  I have looked to just download Delphi 7 but I just cannot find it.

If I am doing something wrong and I am able to import this (plus others as well) via from inside Delphi then what must I do to be able to work with backwards compatibility.

Comment: What do you mean by "get it to work"?  You can't use a Delphi 7 package in XE5.

Comment: @DavidA I am asking for backwards compatibility if that is possible in Delphi XE5 as I have a project in front of me that was done on Delphi 7 which has a lot of deprecation lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi packages are version specific, and named, by convention, with a version number. So, dclsockets70.bpl is the version for Delphi 7. That's no good for you. You need the version for Delphi XE5 which will be dclsockets190.bpl.

The documentation describes the steps needed to install these components: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Installing_Socket_Components

Comment: Oh I understand this 100%, but I have a very old project that I am looking at that was ran on Delphi 7.  As much as I would love to use the newer methods that have been created I do not think it would be in my benefit to go over this whole project and change what has been deprecated (dclsockets70 is just one of them, there are more), I just figured if I can figure this out for dclsockets70 the same would apply for the other old .bpl I would need.

Am I taking a bad approach for time consumption by just grabbing old bpl?  What would you recommend be the smartest option?

Comment: I guess in a nutshell I am asking for backwards compatibility for something that was coded in Delphi 7.  When I am using Delphi XE5 trial version.  Sorry if I seem very unclear as I am very new to Delphi and trying my hardest to get a grasp with this like other languages that I know.

Comment: The first sentence of the answer explains that packages are version specific. Your old code might still work, but you have to use the packages specific to your delphi.

Comment: I did try running it but got a lot of errors, ex) TServerSocket  and Jsocket are not recognized at all as they are deprecated from what I have read.  So from my understanding I would need to find Delphi 7 and use that?

Comment: Maybe. You could stop using these components and use Indy. I'm not sure there's another answer to the question you asked.